# Xcode CI - How to specify in a bot which development team and provisioning profile to use?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, provisioning-profile, xcode-bots

I am setting up an Xcode bot to build and upload our AdHoc app to Crashlytics, and am having issues specifying it to use our Enterprise team and adhoc provisioning profile.

I tried adding these in the .xcconfig file for the scheme, but it seems to ignore it completely (tested by setting the properties to invalid settings and build was still successful):

**AdHoc.xcconfig:**

```
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = My Enterprise Team
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = abc123-abc-123-abc-abc123abc123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I was able to use Xcode 8's `Automatically Manage Code Signing` feature and these settings in the appropriate .xcconfig file:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ABC123ABC
```